# Difference between "to posit" and "to postulate"

Tags: differences, verbs

What exactly is the difference in meaning between the two words *posit* and *postulate*, besides the fact that the latter one is also used as a noun?

---

Both words are formal and their definition are quite equal; in some learners' dictionary they're even identical.

> [postulate](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/postulate)/[posit](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/posit): to suggest (something, such as an idea or theory) especially in order to start a discussion

Based on COCA both words are commonly used with *theory* but *postulate* is the appropriate word for [Khazzoom–Brookes postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khazzoom%E2%80%93Brookes_postulate). But since both words *posit* and *postulate* are not very regularly used, this is the only hint the corpora gives (and BNC contains even less material).

It doesn't look like there's a general tendency to use one word more commonly for a particular area of expertise, for instance science (e.g. astronomy) or religion (existence, God), except the Khazzoom–Brookes postulate, of course. At any rate, it seems like the words can be interchanged.

Answer (score 6):

OED
Postulate: *A fundamental principle, presupposition, or condition, esp. one assumed as the basis of a discipline or theory; (also) a proposition that is (or is claimed should be) taken as granted; esp. one (to be) used as a basis for reasoning or discussion, a premise.*

[A postulate](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/study_guide/Postulates-and-Theorems.topicArticleId-18851,articleId-18770.html) is accepted as true, and it doesn't need to be proven when used as the basis for another argument - it is a fundamental principle and we don't want to be re-inventing the wheel by proving it all over again

OED:
Posit: *To put forward or assume as fact or as a basis for argument, to presuppose; to postulate; to affirm the existence of.*

A posit, in contrast, is assumed on the basis that it will (hopefully) prove to be true. A possible explanation of how something happened is a posit. If you observe (for example) that economic inflation is occurring, you could posit that increasing wages is driving it, and then set out to collect facts to prove or disprove that posit.

Comment: The only context I normally meet "posit" is in computerland. I disremember the specific language (possibly Cobol; it was a *long* time ago), but there was support for *posit/quit* syntax in high-level code. Although processors today still do that kind of stuff internally, mostly people talk about it in terms of *pipelining, prefetching, branch penalty*, etc. But I think you're spot-on when you say "posit" applies to something that *will (**hopefully**) prove to be true* (as opposed to something you *believe after considering the evidence* will be true).

Answer (score 1):

*Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) includes both *posit* and *postulate* (as verbs) in a group of words that also includes *presuppose*, *presume*, *assume*, and *premise*:

> **Presuppose, presume, assume, postulate, premise, posit** agree in meaning to take something for granted as true or existent, especially as a basis for action or reasoning.Their corresponding nouns **presupposition, presumption, assumption, postulate, premise** (or **premiss**)**, position** when they denote that which is taken for granted or is accepted as true or existent are distinguishable in general by the same implications and connotations as the verbs. ... **Postulate**, either as a verb or as a noun, differs from *assume* or *assumption* only in being far more restricted in its application and more exact in its implications. One can *assume* or make an *assumption* at any point in a course of reasoning, but one *postulates* something or lays down a proposition as a *postulate* only as the groundwork for a single argument, or for a chain of reasoning, or for a system of thought. *Postulate*, therefore, has reference to one of the underlying assumptions, which are accepted as true but acknowledged as indemonstrable  and without which thought or action (also artistic representation) is impossible because of the limitations of human knowledge or of human reason (or of art); thus, the ordinary man always *postulates* the reality of time and of space; the dramatist *postulates* certain conventions which it is necessary for the audience to accept; "belief in the uniformity of nature, which is aid to be a *postulate* of science" (*B[ertrand] Russell*); "the prevailing theological system is one which *postulates* the reality of guidance by a personal God" (*A[ldous] Huxley*); "the kind of curvature *postulated* by the generalised theory of relativity" (*[James] Jeans*). ... **Posit** and **position** differ from *postulate* chiefly in implying affirmation as a truth; they rule out the implication of an assumption which is often found found in *postulate* and substitute that of a declaration of faith or conviction. "Hooker...rests his *positions* on one solid basis, the eternal obligation of natural law" (*[Henry] Hallam*). "It seems to me an error to say that we have no grounds for positing the existence of God outside His relation to ourselves" (*[William] Inge*).

The gist of Webster's argument seems to be that both *postulate* and *posit* explicitly acknowledge something as assumed at the outset of an argument or an inquiry or an exposition of a system of action or conduct—but *postulate* makes no commitment to the fundamental correctness of the underlying assumption, whereas *posit* affirms it correctness more or less devotedly.

It is interesting to see how *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984) differs from its predecessor in a similarly long discussion of this group of words, starting with the fact that it identifies the noun form of *posit* as *posit* rather than *position*:

> **presuppose, presume, assume, postulate, premise, posit** are comparable when they mean to take something for granted as true or existent especially as a basis for action or reasoning.Their corresponding nouns **presupposition, presumption, assumption, postulate, premise, posit** when they denote something that is taken for granted or is accepted as true or existent are distinguishable in general by the same implications and connotations as the verbs. ... **Postulate**, either as verb or noun, differs from *assume* or *assumption* in being more restricted in its application and more exact in its implications. One can *assume* or make an *assumption* at any point in a course of reasoning, but one *postulates* something or lays down a proposition as a *postulate* only as the groundwork for a single argument or for a chain of reasoning or for a system of thought. *Postulate*, therefore, has reference to one of the underlying assumptions, which are accepted as true but acknowledged as indemonstrable and without which thought or action or artistic representation is impossible because of the limitations of human knowledge or of human reason or of art {the ordinary man always *postulates* the reality of time and of space} {the dramatist *postulates* certain conventions which it is necessary for the audience to accept} {belief in the uniformity of nature, which is aid to be a *postulate* of science—*[Bertrand] Russell*} {the prevailing theological system is one which *postulates* the reality of guidance by a personal God—*[Aldous] Huxley*} {what I'm postulating in all this ... is that the unconscious, you see, has an enormous teleological sense—*{Norman] Mailer*} ... **Posit**, as a noun and verb, comes close to *postulate* in implying the laying down of a proposition as a base for an argument, a line of reasoning, or a system of thought, but it may differ in suggesting subjective and arbitrary grounds rather than, as *postulate* regularly does, objective and rational grounds for selection of the proposition {if she needs salvation, she will *posit* a savior—*[George] Santayana*} {he did not *posit* a world of wormless apples to set off the fruit he reported in such wonderful detail—*[Peter?] Gratton*} {materialism at that time *posited* the premise that character was the product of environment, and this was the basis of Zola's naturalism—*[James?] Farrell*} but even when it connotes  actual falsity it remains very close to postulate {such *posits* or postulated entities are myths from the standpoint of the level below them, the phenomenalistic level—*[Douglas] Hofstadter*} {kill or be killed the sergeants cried, discriminating Die from Live, and spoke the truth. And also lied, *posited* false alternative—*[William] Gibson*}

Evidently a sea change in the meanings of *postulate* and *posit* occurred between 1942 and 1984. In 1942 Webster's argues that *postulate* has an arm's-length relationship to its central assumption, while *posit* tends to embrace and believe in its assumption, to the point of treating it not as an assumption but as a point of faith. But in 1984 Merriam-Webster emphasizes the objectivity and rationality of *postulate* versus the subjectivity and arbitrariness of *posit*. The 1942 distinction focuses on the speaker's attitude toward the thing assumed, while the 1984 distinction seems to focus on the legitimacy or scientific defensibility of making the assumption.

I'm inclined to view Merriam-Webster's 1984 distinction between scientific *postulating* and capricious *positing* as an overstatement of the difference in how people actually use the two words. Certainly the mathematical prominence given to postulates in both Euclidean and non-Euclidean systems of geometry attaches a rigor to *postulate* that *posit* doesn't possess. But even if *posit* often indicates a speaker's rooting interest in the correctness of the asserted assumption, it needn't be altogether subjective and arbitrary. I confess that I don't see a particularly bright line separating Merriam-Webster's Huxley example ("the prevailing theological system is one which *postulates* the reality of guidance by a personal God") from its Santayana example ("if she needs salvation, she will *posit* a savior") with regard to objectivity/subjectivity or rationality/arbitrariness.